# Product of disjoint cycle example

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

$(123)(45)(15)(24) = (14)(235)$, according to my lecture notes, yet I keep getting $(143)(25)$. By doing
$$1 \to 4\\
4 \to 3\\
3 \to 1\\
2 \to 5\\
5 \to 2$$
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You get one answer (lecture notes) by evaluating left to right; and the other answer (your answer) by evaluating right to left.

Comment: And actually AFAIK right to left (yours) is more standard as in consistent with usual composition.

Answer (score 0):

After $(123)$ we have $31245$.

After $(45)$ we have $31254$.

After $(15)$ we have $41253$.

After $(24)$ we have $45213$.

which gives $(14)(235)$.